# Why does GCC under Rosetta 2 not compile properly Python

Tags: python, gcc, compilation, apple-m1, rosetta

I have installed an Item and pyenv according this :
https://medium.com/thinknum/how-to-install-python-under-rosetta-2-f98c0865e012
In addition I have installed gcc-11 under the rosetta terminal

But when compile Python 3.7 with CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-11 pyenv86 install -v 3.7.0 I get compile errors I can't interpret I am not a C guy. Can anybody help me out and tell me what is wrong. And how I can compile python under rosetta 2. The log You find under kargers.org/help/p.log (its too long for this). I think the compiler mixes up things from brew(arm) and things from brew86 which are stored in different locations but how can I avoid this.

Comment: Are you doing this because you need to run a particular Python library that has to run under Rosetta 2?  Just asking in case you saw that old blog post and thought it was necessary in all cases. But newer Python versions since `3.9.1` run natively on M1 and life is much easier not having to run two brew paths etc etc

Comment: Yes. I need Scribus. In Scribus there is scripter and in Scripter I need Pillow. Scribus runs under rosetta. At the moment I use my old 2012 MAC for Scribus....but its endless slow despite 16G and SSD....  So I want to port the whole thing to my new MAC M1. Scribus uses its own Python somehow but has access to the system libs. On my old Mac I installed PIL (Pillow) and had access to it within Scribus. The plan is to build a complete rosetta env only for Scribus....Until Scribus is on M1.....